# How to modify the value of an object when it is cloned?

Tags: javascript

Given the following object

```
const data = {
  "123-456": {
    "03": 2,
    "04": 0,
    "05": 0,
    "06": 0,
    "07": 0,
    "08": 1,
    "09": 1
  },
  "123-789": {
    "03": 2,
    "04": 0,
    "05": 0,
    "06": 0,
    "07": 0,
    "08": 1,
    "09": 1
  }
};
```

And the following variables

```
const value = 10;
const weekday = "03";
const id = "123-456";
```

I need to create a copy of the `data` object where the value of the `id` and day of the given week changes. So given the previous parameters the new object would be the following.

```
{
  "123-456": {
    "03": 10, // <- here the new value
    "04": 0,
    "05": 0,
    "06": 0,
    "07": 0,
    "08": 1,
    "09": 1
  },
  "123-789": {
    "03": 2,
    "04": 0,
    "05": 0,
    "06": 0,
    "07": 0,
    "08": 1,
    "09": 1
  }
}
```

And tried to make a copy but without success

This is some of my tries

```
const newData = { ...data, [id]: { ...data[id], data[id][weekday]: value } };
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small change to your code `const newData = { ...data, [id]: { ...data[id], [weekday]: value } };`.

```js
const data = {
  "123-456": {
    "03": 2,
    "04": 0,
    "05": 0,
    "06": 0,
    "07": 0,
    "08": 1,
    "09": 1
  },
  "123-789": {
    "03": 2,
    "04": 0,
    "05": 0,
    "06": 0,
    "07": 0,
    "08": 1,
    "09": 1
  }
};

const value = 10;
const weekday = "03";
const id = "123-456";

const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ ...data, [id]: { ...data[id], [weekday]: value } }));

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, well observed, it works as expected

Comment: this is wrong , newData is not a clone. the part  "123-789" are on the same object

Comment: newData is not a clone object but it is the same object. I have made edit for the same kindly review it.

Answer (score 0):

a real cloning way

```js
const data = 
      { "123-456": { "03": 2, "04": 0, "05": 0, "06": 0, "07": 0, "08": 1, "09": 1 } 
      , "123-789": { "03": 2, "04": 0, "05": 0, "06": 0, "07": 0, "08": 1, "09": 1 } 
      };

const value   = 10
  ,   weekday = "03"
  ,   id      = "123-456"
  ;

// cloning 
const newData = {...data}
for (let key in newData)
  { newData[key] = {...data[key]} }

// set value 
newData[id][weekday] = value

newData['123-789']['04'] = 999  // just for test

//proof
console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data,0,2) )
console.log('newData', JSON.stringify(newData,0,2) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; width: 40% !important; top: 0; left: 60% !important; }
```